# Securing remote mysql connection

Tags: php, mysql, ms-access

I'm in the unfortunate position of having to sync a local microsoft access database with a remote mysql database.

I have written a php script which will sync the databases every 10 minutes.  However I'm definitely concerned about security.

So far I have set up remote mysql with cpanel, this allows only my I.P address to make connections.  I've also made sure the user I'm connecting with has limited permissions.

However, I'm aware that the data I'll be sending back and forth will be unencrypted.  Is there anything I can do to make sure my data is encrypted?  I'd also like to know whether my mysql username/password is currently encrypted the way I have it set up?

Lucas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use secure connection to MySQL:

MySQL side: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/secure-connections.html

PHP side: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-connect.php (MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL flag)

I have not worked with SSL connections to MySQL with PHP, but, I think it is not hard to find needed information on http://php.net, http://dev.mysql.com and http://google.com

**Update**

This may help: http://www.madirish.net/node/244, [PHP to MySQL SSL Connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3657765/php-to-mysql-ssl-connections), http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.ssl-set.php

Comment: Those links at the bottom are very helpful.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the PHP mcrypt functions to encrypt and decrypt the data.

A good example of this can be found right on SOF: [Best way to use PHP to encrypt and decrypt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289061/best-way-to-use-php-to-encrypt-and-decrypt)

Comment: Thanks, but this way I have to write a script on the server to decrypt and perform mysql operations.  Its quicker to make remote mysql changes directly from my local machine.  I was thinking I could maybe connect using SSH or something, but I don't really know how to go about it.  The option you've given I may try if I find there simply isn't another secure way of doing this.