# Form info to database on another server

Tags: database, registration

I have two websites; `website1.com` and `website2.com`. On `website1` I have database with customer information and a neat CMS. Now I would like to make a registration form on `website2` and insert that information in the database on `website1`.

Is this possible? Can I simply use `mysql INSERT INTO~`? Or do I need to use something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can connect remotely to another server:

```
mysql -h host_name -D db_name -ppassword -c "insert into ..."
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow MySQL remote connections if your websites are on different machines. [*Securing Remote MySQL*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9004249/securing-remote-mysql-connection)

In both cases (remote or local), the method is the same: [open a connection](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) to website1's database and use `INSERT INTO`.