# Connect to remote MySQL server with SSL from PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ssl

I'm trying to connect to remote MySQL server with SSL from PHP using mysql_connect:

```
$link = mysql_connect(
    "ip",
    "user",
    "pass",
    true,
    MYSQL_CLIENT_SSL
)
```

And get worst error ever:

```
SSL connection error
```

I've added following params into my.cnf:

```
[client]
ssl-ca      =/etc/mysql/ssl/ca-cert.pm
ssl-cert    =/etc/mysql/ssl/client-cert.pem
ssl-key     =/etc/mysql/ssl/client-key.pem
```

So I can connect to remote mysql successfully from terminal just using

```
#mysql -h ip -u user -p
```

So connection to mysql server do work and as far as I understand problem is in php/mysql cooperation. Probably I'm missing some params.

Unfortunately I can't use mysqli lib because have too many working adapters for pdo_mysql.

My PHP Version is 5.3.6-13ubuntu3.6
MySQL version is 5.1.61

Also I've added

```
mssql.secure_connection = On
```

to my php.ini

Help will be appreciated!

Comment: if you're using MySQL, shouldn't you be setting `mysql.secure_connection = On`?

Comment: @SorinButurugeanu there is no option called `mysql.secure_connection` in php.ini!!

Comment: Are you talking about MySQL or MSSQL, like given in the configuration line?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

> "Unfortunately I can't use mysqli lib because have too many working adapters for pdo_mysql."

You're using the old MySQL extension ("mysql_connect"), which is no longer under development ([maintenance only](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php)). Since you're using PHP 5, you may want to use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php), the MySQL *Improved* Extension. Among other things, it has an object-oriented interface, support for prepared/multiple statements and has enhanced debugging capabilities. You can read more about converting to MySQLi [here](http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/Converting_to_MySQLi); more about the mysqli class itself [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php).

Here is some sample code that may help you get started:

```
<?php
ini_set ('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set ('display_errors', '1');
error_reporting (E_ALL|E_STRICT);

$db = mysqli_init();
mysqli_options ($db, MYSQLI_OPT_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT, true);

$db->ssl_set('/etc/mysql/ssl/client-key.pem', '/etc/mysql/ssl/client-cert.pem', '/etc/mysql/ssl/ca-cert.pem', NULL, NULL);
$link = mysqli_real_connect ($db, 'ip', 'user', 'pass', 'db', 3306, NULL, MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL);
if (!$link)
{
    die ('Connect error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . '): ' . mysqli_connect_error() . "\n");
} else {
    $res = $db->query('SHOW TABLES;');
    print_r ($res);
    $db->close();
}
?>
```

If [PDO_MYSQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) is really what you want, then you need to do something like this:

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=ip;dbname=db', 'user', 'pass', array(
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY    =>'/etc/mysql/ssl/client-key.pem',
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT=>'/etc/mysql/ssl/client-cert.pem',
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA    =>'/etc/mysql/ssl/ca-cert.pem'
    )
);
$statement = $pdo->query("SHOW TABLES;");
$row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo htmlentities($row['_message']);
?>
```

However, only recent versions of PHP have SSL support for PDO, and SSL options are silently ignored in (at least) version 5.3.8: see the [bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=55870).

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

if your using PHP 7.3 and AWS PEM file  , Use below code to connect DB with ssl

```
UR AWS PEM FILE PATH =/home/cert/rds2019.pem
$mysqli = mysqli_init();
$mysqli->ssl_set(NULL,NULL,'UR AWS PEM FILE PATH',NULL,'DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA');
$mysqli->options(MYSQLI_OPT_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT, true);
$mysqli->real_connect($dbHostName, $dbUserName, $dbPassword, $dataBaseName,PORT,NULL, MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL);
```

return $mysqli;

**For PDO Connection**

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.$dbHostName.';dbname='.$dataBaseName.'', $dbUserName, $dbPassword, array(
            //PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY    =>NULL,

            //PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT=>NULL,

            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA    =>'UR AWS PEM FILE PATH',
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CAPATH    =>NULL,
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CIPHER    =>'DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA',
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT => false
            )
        );
return $pdo;
```

Comment: Would you please explain why MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT is set to false here ? Wouldn't that disable certificate verification ?

Answer (score 0):

Change `[client]` header to `[mysqld]`. You need to setup server side certificates there, not client side.

See a full [example](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-security-excerpt/5.0/en/creating-ssl-files-using-openssl.html) from MySQL documentation.

Also, see this similar question: [PHP to MySQL SSL Connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3657765/php-to-mysql-ssl-connections)

Server certificates allow the server to respond to SSL requests, and they don't require the client to have a certificate. Any time you connect to a web site via HTTPS, you are using the server's certificates to verify that you are connecting to the correct server, and you are using the certificate's public key for encryption.

Client certificates allow a server to authenticate the client.

In your case, you want server certificates. You want to install the certificates on the server (MySQL), and the client (PHP) will be able to authenticate the server and use the certificate's public key for setting up encryption. Client certificates are fairly rare.

If you do wish to utilize client certificates, you must use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.ssl-set.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php).

Comment: Thank you Marcus, but this is a client side configuration. After adding this params I can connect to server without adding --ssl-... params.

Comment: @AlexeyBulash, I updated my answer to further explain the difference between client and server certificates.

Comment: @MarcusAdams, your link is broken now.