# Secure remote MySQL connection via https

Tags: mysql, security

I'm using software to access MySQL remotely. Can I connect to the database via https so the connection is safe?

For example, using a host of https://mydomain.com.

Answer (score 1):

HTTPS is for connecting to web servers, not database servers. See the following MySQL documentation:

[Using SSL for Secure Connections](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/ssl-connections.html)

How you use this from an application will depend on the language and driver. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9738712/connect-to-remote-mysql-server-with-ssl-from-php?lq=1) for how to do it using PHP with the MySQLi extension.