# SSL encrypted ZF2 PDO connection to Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, ssl, pdo, zend-framework2

Is it possible to make an SSL encrypted connection via ZF2 to my MySql Server?
And if yes, how is it possible?
I can't find anything for ZF2 PDO SSL connection on the web.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9738712/connect-to-remote-mysql-server-with-ssl-from-php, you might need to edit core files though, dont use ZF2 but its obviously possible

Answer (score 3):

```
return array(
    'db' => array(
        'adapters' => array(
            // The first (default) database connection
            'zf2' => array(
                'driver' => 'pdo',
                'dsn' => 'mysql:dbname=zf2;host=sandbox-db-vm',
                'username' => 'root',
                'password' => 'password',
            ),
            // Now the second database connection
            'zf2ssl' => array(
                'driver' => 'pdo',
                'dsn' => 'mysql:dbname=zf2;host=sandbox-db-vm',
                'username' => 'ssl_user',
                'password' => 'ssl_test',
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY  => '/etc/mysql-ssl/client-key.pem',
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT => '/etc/mysql-ssl/client-cert.pem',
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA   => '/etc/mysql-ssl/ca-cert.pem'
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'service_manager' => array(
        // Let's make sure our adapters get instantiated
        'abstract_factories' => array(
            'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterAbstractServiceFactory',
        ),
    ),
);
```