# MySQL SSL connection php 5.3.3

Tags: php, mysql, ssl

I am trying to connect from a PHP application to a MySQL database using SSL.

I know I can connect via SSL since PHP 5.3.7, but I have  PHP 5.3.3 installed and use the pdo_mysql driver.

Can I connect anyway  by changing the PHP configuration file, by installing some modules or any other way?

Comment: This may be a dup or it just might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9738712/connect-to-remote-mysql-server-with-ssl-from-php But it looks like PHP5.3.3 is just TOO ANCIENT to work

Comment: Adding on to @RiggsFolly, PHP 5.3.3 was released in 22 Jul 2010 and is so old and not supported it no longer exists on the PHP end of life page. https://secure.php.net/supported-versions.php That being said, I found this doing some searching: https://serverfault.com/questions/640579/ssl-support-for-php-5-3-3-and-apache