# Connect to MariaDB by using PDO with accept server cert

Tags: php, ssl, pdo, mariadb-10.5

I can connect the database with Maria client with --ssl options on application server:

> mariadb -h [Address] -P [Port] -u [DB admin user] -p --ssl

But tried to connect the same database on same server with PHP PDO, we got the error message with:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requested authentication method unknown to the client[client_ed25519]

I have added below options to PDO connection for simulate the --ssl options

```
   PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => true,
   PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT => false,
```

Here is my testing code piece:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$options = [
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => true,
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT => false,
];

try {
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=myDB", $username, $password, $options);
  // set the PDO error mode to exception
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  echo "Connected successfully";
} catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Database version: MariaDB 10.5

Comment: One more response message:
The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [client_ed25519]

Comment: Does this question help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9738712/connect-to-remote-mysql-server-with-ssl-from-php

Comment: The following is what we're using in our application
```$conn->exec("SET GLOBAL ssl_ca = '/etc/mysql/cacert.pem'");```
```$conn->exec("SET GLOBAL ssl_verify_server_cert = 1");```

Comment: Server: PHP8.0
MariaDB 10.5

Comment: Thanks es!mo_, but it is require the client cert and key provided, but may we same as client to trust server cert instead.

Comment: I found the problem is unable to process the authentication method by ed25519 which is database server is using and we unable to change it. May I know if PHP-MYSQLND is supported this authentication method or not.