# PHP connect to MS SQL with SSL

Tags: php, sql, ubuntu, ssl

What I mean to achieve is very simple. I want to connect to an external MS SQL database from a PHP script over a secure connection. This has however proven problematic and, with three hours put in to research so far, I am at a loss.

The platform for the client is Ubuntu, which means I can not use SQLSRV.
The secure connection has been tested with different clients and it works fine.
I am currently using PDO and DBlib to connect to the database, which also works fine.

I was not able to find any method to force a secure connection. I have tried multiple other drivers, to no avail.

What are my options?

Edit: I am left with the following FreeTDS logs...

```
config.c:543:   Got a match.
config.c:565:   host = 'XXXXXXXXXX'
config.c:595:   Found host entry XXXXXXXXXX.
config.c:599:   IP addr is XXXXXXXXXX.
config.c:565:   port = '1433'
config.c:565:   encryption = 'require'
config.c:565:   check certificate hostname = 'no'
config.c:629:   UNRECOGNIZED option 'check certificate hostname' ... ignoring.
config.c:565:   ca file = 'XXXXXXXXXX.pem'
config.c:629:   UNRECOGNIZED option 'ca file' ... ignoring.
```

Comment: What errors have you received?

Comment: None, I have queried the server to check if the connection was encrypted, it was not. I would LOVE some errors by now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use PDO, you could set up PDO ODBC. You will need to setup the configuration files `/etc/odbc.ini`, `/etc/odbcinst.ini` and `/etc/freetds/freetds.conf`.

You'll also have to install unixodbc and freetds: `apt-get install unixodbc tdsodbc`.

You can see more info here: [Connect PHP to MSSQL via PDO ODBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20163776/connect-php-to-mssql-via-pdo-odbc)

**EDIT:** To enforce SSL in ODBC, add the `Encrypt` keyword and set it to true in your connection string. And setup your SQL Server to use SSL: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/316898

**EDIT 2:** According to the OP, adding `encryption=require` and `check certificate hostname` to freetds.config as per the following specification: http://www.freetds.org/userguide/freetdsconf.htm along with the above steps will fix the problem

Comment: I would consider this, though I can't find any specific means to force an SSL connection for ODBC.

Comment: Isn't the Encrypt keyword available when using dblib?

Comment: I have configured `ODBC`, it works correctly. I have added the `Encrypt` keyword to the `odbc.ini`, yet it still does not encrypt the connection. It still does not throw any errors either. The server is configured to accept both encrypted and plain connections.

The query I use to check the connection is `SELECT encrypt_option FROM sys.dm_exec_connections WHERE session_id = @@SPID`.

I'm pretty certain `Encrypt` is not available in the ODBC DSN, though I'm aware that it is used for `PDO_SQLSRV`

Comment: To force a secure connection one might append `encryption=require` to `freetds.config` as per the following specification: `http://www.freetds.org/userguide/freetdsconf.htm` Another useful atribute is `check certificate hostname`. Please update your answer to include all relevant information.

Comment: @SamuelWillems Did it work with `encryption=require` and `check certificate hostname`?

Comment: provided that the certificate is either valid or added as trusted root certificate. There does not seem to be an attribute to completely disable certificate verification.

Comment: @SamuelWillems I made the edit. Can you mark it as the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Have you configured `mssql_connect` to use a secure connection? Look in your `php.ini` and verify the `mssql.secure_connection` parameter is set to on

```
[MSSQL]
mssql.secure_connection = On
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your reply. I didn't want to use `mssql_connect` since it's deprecated. I have, however, indeed tried to change this setting and use `mssql_connect`. I've installed the certificate in `/etc/ssl/certs` as well. 

I was wondering how I might debug this, I currently have no idea what is going wrong. Does it not even try to connect over SSL or is it running in to a problem and defaulting to plain?