# PHP [Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now] on new mysqli();

Tags: php, mysqli

I have created a class in PHP to handle most of the work dealing with the MySQL database.
Here is a code example:

```
class DataAccessBase
{
protected $sql_wr;
protected $sql_ro;

function __construct()
{
    $this->sql_wr = new mysqli();
    $this->sql_ro = new mysqli();

    $this->sql_wr->ssl_set(DB_WR_SSLKEY, DB_WR_SSLCERT, DB_WR_SSLCA, NULL, NULL);
    $this->sql_ro->ssl_set(DB_RO_SSLKEY, DB_RO_SSLCERT, DB_RO_SSLCA, NULL, NULL);
}
```

When the constructor runs, I get "Commands out of sync..." error on the new mysqli();. Both of them.
All of the searching I have done discusses incorrect code trying to do multiple queries. I get the error before I even open the connection.
What am I missing?
I have tried using the mysqli_init() also and it returns the same error.

Comment: Do you really have no parameters in the `new mysqli()` [See manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php)

Comment: I really do. I am using real_connect in another function.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: Do you have the `php_openssl` extension activated ?

Comment: Probably Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3657765/php-to-mysql-ssl-connections

Comment: It would appear that I have 7.0.15 installed.

Comment: Have you set MySQL up to expect secure connections?

Comment: I read thru the article, thank you for the link. I have the server setup properly. I can connect to it using ssl from within PHPStorm, Visual Studio, and MySQL Workbench.

Comment: @RiggsFolly thank you for your insight.

Answer (score 0):

I change my code to add the parameters to the mysqli() call.

```
$this->sql_wr = new mysqli(DB_WR_HOST, DB_WR_USER, DB_WR_PASS, DBNAME);
```

I no longer get the error on the new.
I now have other errors, but I will open a new question if needed.